# Generic C# - how to use reflection to assign properties to generic class

Tags: c#, generic-programming, system.reflection

I would like to assign values to various classes. How I would achieve the code below would work?

```
T row = new T();
row[propertyName1] = "value 1";
row[propertyName2] = "value 2";
row[propertyName3] = "value 3";
```

I have various classes. I have property names for each class with values.

What I am trying to do is to assign all table values from database to classes Lists. All classes in C# are exact match to tables in SQL. Entitiy framework do this. I would like to build the same functionality as EF do.

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem, What is the use case here, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use such thing using reflexion:

```
using System.Reflection;

static void Test()
{
  var list = new List<int>();
  list.SetProperty("Capacity", 10);
}

static BindingFlags DefaultBindingFlags
  = BindingFlags.Public
  | BindingFlags.Static
  | BindingFlags.Instance;

static void SetProperty<T>(this T instance, string name, object value)
//where T : ...
{
  PropertyInfo p = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Capacity", DefaultBindingFlags);
  if ( p != null )
    p.SetValue(instance, value, null);
  else
    throw new Exception($"Property {name} doesn't exist.");
}
```